# IF statement in MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, if-statement, triggers

This is my query code in MySQL trigger.

```
if 1=2 then
    select 'Yes';
else
    select 'No';
end if;
```

But has the following Error:

```
if '1'='2' then    select 'Yes' Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if '1'='2' then    select 'Yes'' at line 1 0.000 sec
```

What is the solution?

Comment: Problem must be in the statements before the `if ...` statement. You better post the trigger body.

Comment: My problem is just this code

Comment: Post the complete trigger code.

Comment: @user2545982: Posted code has no errors. Usually error stack shows a statement point *before* of which there exists an error.  Example: `... for the right syntax to user *near* 'if '1'=...`

Answer (score 0):

The right syntax for If statement In MySQL is

```
IF (Expression) THEN
               body;
ELSE
           body;
END IF;
```

also, `1=2` is not an expression
it must be some condition like `var>1` or `var<2`.